# Error using preact-compt Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: h is not defined

Tags: reactjs, preact

I want to use some React compatible packages in my preact app. I have followed the instructions for installing preact-compat. Now when I add a React component to the app, I need to still import 'h' from preact, otherwise I get the error: 
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: h is not defined. For example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { h } from 'preact';

export default class TestForm extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render(props, state) { console.log('TestForm::render');
    return (
      <div>Hello</div>
    );
  }

}
```

If I don't import 'h' from react, the error occurs. How can I fix this?

I am using Browserify and Babel and made the following changes:
In package.json:

```
"aliasify": {
    "aliases": {
        "react": "preact-compat",
        "react-dom": "preact-compat",
        // Not necessary unless you consume a module using `createClass`
        "create-react-class": "preact-compat/lib/create-react-class",
        // Not necessary unless you consume a module requiring `react-dom-factories`
        "react-dom-factories": "preact-compat/lib/react-dom-factories"
    }
}
```

and in .babelrc:

```
"plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
    "root": ["."],
    "alias": {
        "react": "preact-compat",
        "react-dom": "preact-compat",
        // Not necessary unless you consume a module using `createClass`
        "create-react-class": "preact-compat/lib/create-react-class",
        // Not necessary unless you consume a module requiring `react-dom-factories`
        "react-dom-factories" "preact-compat/lib/react-dom-factories"
    }
    }]
],
"presets": [
    "react"
]
```

Comment: You need to change the pragma from `h` to `React.createElement`, and how to do that depends on what environment you are developing your app in.

Comment: I edited my question to include more about the environment I'm developing in. . .is that enough to tell me where to insert this pragma? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to you babel config

```
plugins: [
     ["@babel/transform-react-jsx", { pragma: "h" }]
 ],
```